# SyntaxError: invalid token

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a sudoku game that receives user input and then plays with the user. 
when I run the code from Pychram everything works, however when I try to run it from the terminal I get this error: `"SyntaxError: invalid token"`
I'm using the same input on the same code.
do you know how I might be able to fix it?
the function:

```
def get_board():
    board = []
    for idx in range(9):
        user_input = str(input(""))
        temp_lst = [val for val in user_input]
        board.append(temp_lst)
    return board
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw5q1.py", line 169, in <module>
    main()
  File "hw5q1.py", line 165, in main
    sudoko()
  File "hw5q1.py", line 127, in sudoko
    board = get_board()
  File "hw5q1.py", line 4, in get_board
    user_input = str(input(""))
  File "<string>", line 1
    034678912
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

The Input:
034678912
672195308
098342567
809061423
426853790
713920056
960537204
287409635
345086109

thanks!

Comment: Are you running this on Python 2 instead of 3?

Comment: I've tried running it on both python 2 and 3 in 3 it doesn't say there is a problem but the output file is empty

Comment: What output file? There's nothing related in your code.